# Creating a Laravel project returns error "No system CA bundle could be found"

Tags: laravel

I have installed Laravel. Now I want to create project with command (`laravel new foldername`) but I'm getting error like this:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]

  No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations.
  PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's
  CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to
  supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request
  option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not
  need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA
  bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL):
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once
  you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP
  ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify'
  request option.
```

Comment: What version of PHP do you have installed?

Comment: PHP version 5.4.12

Answer (score 1):

I would upgrade your PHP version.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

PHP >= 5.6.4

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a Guzzle issue not a laravel pure one. anyway try this out.

1- Download this file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it somewhere in your computer. for example, c:/xampp/cacert.pem

2- Open your php.ini config file

3- Look for the following config and uncomment it if it exists or add it if it does not:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo=c:/xampp/cacert.pem
```

Comment: I m using Windows 10 and Wamp Server

Comment: no matter what's amp software you're using it's about php itself. I'm using win10 and xampp and just set a new laravel project using the installer -like you did- with no problem on php 5.6

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is well documented and i will suggest you to go through documentation first for installation process. There are few basic requirements need to be fulfilled:

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4

Your question was voted negative because you have not explained your problem clearly. As per my understanding you want to create project by command like composer create-project  {Name of the project}

There is nothing to do with laravel to create project by command. Composer is doing all of this stuff for us. Just install composer first then try to create project by using composer create-project command.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation  you can create a project using the Laravel Installer: laravel new blog. He just needs to upgrade his PHP version.

Comment: @mick Yes you are right. We can create project with laravel command line. However i have mentioned in my answer that question is not very clear that's why i suggested him to use composer and i have also mentioned about basic requirements for Laravel. Unfortunately i was typing the answer and saw your reply after posting my answer.